# Flask response setting is not working in Bluemix Flask Buildpack

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying deploying my flask application to the Bluemix where it is configured by Bluemix Python Flask BuildPack and it is not a custom build back.

```
@app.route('/run',  methods=['GET','POST'])
def stockModuleRunner():
    stockCode =  request.args.get("stock_code","")

    # Store the reference, in case you want to show things again in standard output
    old_stdout = sys.stdout

    # This variable will store everything that is sent to the standard output
    result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = result

    # Here we can call anything
    # Here we can call anything we like, like external modules, and everything that they will send to standard output will be stored on "result"
    r = Resilience.Resilience()
    r.main(stockCode)

    # Redirect again the std output to screen
    sys.stdout = old_stdout

    # Then, get the stdout like a string and process it!
    result_string = result.getvalue()

    print(result_string)

    #r = Resilience.Resilience()
    #r.main(stockCode)

    resp =  Response("<html><pre>"+result_string+"</pre></html>")
    resp.headers['content-type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    return
```

I set the content type of my response as a text/html. But it didn't work in the Bluemix, while it worked in my local environment. In the Bluemix, it changed to text/xml automatically. I confirmed it through the network tab of chrome developer tool. I got the error like the followings. As per the result of a google search, I found out that it is a sort of xml parsing error. Do you have any idea of this problem?

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Comment: Please provide details on what you are seeing? Typically, you don't set the reponse header. Is this for a regular http request with a HTML page returned?

Comment: @data_henrik I updated my question.

Comment: Wouldn't you in Flask define a route, compose a string and return it and Flask would treat it as HTML automatically? Could you provide a longer code snippet?

Comment: @data_henrik I uploaded all of my source, the problem of mine is that Bluemix change the content type of my response to text/xml. I want it to be text/html,

Comment: IMHO this is untypical how you use Flask to obtain arguments and how to compose the reponse. Just assemble a string and return it. No response object required.

Comment: @data_henrik Yes as you said, I could help but returning a raw string